# Extracting JSON Objects sharing the same name from API Call JSON response into an array using Java

Tags: java, json

I am making weather forecast app using Android Studio, Java and OpenWeatherAPI. I got stuck on a problem and can't find solution. It is a JSON response I get from API:

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1672812000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 277.75,
        "feels_like": 273.5,
        "temp_min": 277.75,
        "temp_max": 279.26,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "sea_level": 1014,
        "grnd_level": 1015,
        "humidity": 85,
        "temp_kf": -1.51
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 29
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.1,
        "deg": 197,
        "gust": 15.31
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2023-01-04 06:00:00"
    },
    
    {
      "dt": 1672844400,
      "main": {
        "temp": 282.13,
        "feels_like": 278.47,
        "temp_min": 282.13,
        "temp_max": 282.13,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "sea_level": 1012,
        "grnd_level": 1007,
        "humidity": 84,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 8.08,
        "deg": 234,
        "gust": 18.26
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 1,
      "rain": {
        "3h": 2.84
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2023-01-04 15:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1673233200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 280.69,
        "feels_like": 277.6,
        "temp_min": 280.69,
        "temp_max": 280.69,
        "pressure": 998,
        "sea_level": 998,
        "grnd_level": 993,
        "humidity": 72,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 88
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.14,
        "deg": 207,
        "gust": 12.85
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2023-01-09 03:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2950159,
    "name": "Berlin",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 52.5244,
      "lon": 13.4105
    },
    "country": "DE",
    "population": 1000000,
    "timezone": 3600,
    "sunrise": 1672816596,
    "sunset": 1672844715
  }
}
```

And my question is: Is there a way to extract all keys for example "weather"

```
    "weather": [ 
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04n"
        }
      ],
```

into and array (of JSONObjects?) so the information can be accessed like this or in similiar fashion:

```
weather_arrray[i].getString("description")
```

I have been searching online for solution using libraries like Gson or Jackson but I didn't find any clues how to get it done. I am opened to any other ideas if putting it in arrays is not correct approach. I just need to be able to easily access info from for example 1st, 4th or 27th etc. "weather" or lets say "main" occurence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using dynamic `JSON Parsor`.

If your response contains JSONObject, then store it as a JSONObject, OR if your response contains JSONArray, then store it as a JSONArray.

*Pass your response as an argument inside below function, and check that.*

Here `Iterator` is used to fetch dynamic key names from JSONObject.

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(key + ":" + data.getString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(key + ":" + data.getString(key));
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```